# How to fix a NameError while trying to call the "date" command with a format string

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to make a display for my raspberry pi that shows the day of the week, day of the month, the abbreviated month, and the current time. Here is the current code I am trying to run:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "date +"%a %b %d %r""
date = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jc-yeti/oled3.py", line 3, in <module>
    cmd = "date +"%a %b %d %r""
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

When I run the same command in the terminal it works just fine, what am I missing?

Comment: thank you mkrieger1 that fixed my issue. still really new to python.

Comment: The error said that variable `a` is not defined. 

You can define `a`, `b`, `d`, and `r` first to solve the issue.